# Reading from FIFO in nc (netcat)

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, pipe, netcat

I have a bunch of log files that I'd like to watch as they get updated. I came up with the script below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if at least one log file is provided
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 /path/to/log/file1 [/path/to/log/file2 ...]"
    exit 1
fi

if -p pipe_log
then 
    echo "Deleting existing pipe"
    rm pipe_log
    echo "Done!"
fi

mkfifo pipe_log

echo "Setting up log publishing"
# Start tail on each log file and pipe to nc in the background
for log_file in "$@"; do
    (tail -n 0 -F "$log_file"  >> pipe_log) &
done
echo "Done!"

echo "Starting server"
(nc -lk -p 12345 -s 0.0.0.0 < pipe_log ) 
echo "Finished"


# Wait for all background processes to finish
wait

rm pipe_log
```

I consolidate the logs by writing the `tail` of each file to a named pipe.
I then publish the consolidated logs with `nc -lk < pipe_log`. But if I try to read the logs with `nc localhost 12345` there is no output.

I can read directly from the FIFO with `cat pip_log` so there has to be an issue with redirecting from the pipe to `nc` that I cannot nail down.

> Note: The question was earlier posted on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77897429/490648) but received no replies.